# How to fix the db connection error using cypress-sql-server plugin with cypress 10

Tags: javascript, sql-server, database, cypress

I am getting error message as displayed in the image

[image]

I have installed the cypress-sql-server plugin

package.json

[image]

cypress.config.js

[image]

e2e.js file has imported the plugin

[image]

Test file

[image]

How to resolve this error? or how to connect to MsSQL server db using new cypress 10+? I am currently on latest cypress version 12.8.1

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. Please read [ask] and [edit] your question to add formatted code. For more information, please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/20153035), along with [this website](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)